# Unwanted users showing in User Profile Service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, user-profile-service, sharepoint-on-prem

I've created a sync connection with Active Directory in the User Profile Service Application. When the connection was created, some OUs were deselected. Somehow, though, users within these OUs were imported anyways. Now our SharePoint system accounts and [one of our] terminated employees are showing up in the employee directory.

I've tried deleting and re-adding the sync connection with AD.

We also went as far as adding a custom attribute in AD ("employeeDirectory", returns true or false) and using the exclusion filters. The exclusion filters do not seem to be working, either, though (tested by adding a few different filters, then a full crawl).

Do we need to remove the UPSA and re-create it? Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Were they imported or did they access the farm and have a profile create that way. Import is not the only way to create a profile.

Comment: They were imported. None of the "problem profile" users would have accessed the farm.

Comment: Actually, the SPAdmin account has! That solves that one. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you actually seeing logged entries for the users in question? If so you need to change your connection filter to exclude them.

Comment: Yes, I am. I've set up an exclusion filter, but it doesn't seem to be keeping them out. Any ideas on why the exclusion filter my not be working? I've tried excluding based on the custom `employeeDirectory` property, and also by first name (our admin accounts have the same first name property). Neither seems to be excluding anything.

Comment: Are you certain that they are in the Import log? That is not the only way profiles get created. For example, if you log in as the account and access the farm, a profile will be created. Otherwise your filter needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, they were definitely imported, not just created at logon. Fortunately, I've found a work-around: filter in the search web part. It doesn't get rid of the profiles completely, but removes them from our employee directory, which was the important part for us.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: OK, if they are imported then you need to fix your import filter.

Comment: When I populate containers for my import, all of the correct OUs appear. Then I uncheck the OUs that I don't want to import, but users in those OUs still end up imported... Could there be something else I'm doing wrong in my import filter? It *seems* pretty straightforward.

Comment: Again, I would start with the import logs and confirm that it's really the import, if you are getting users from other unchecked OUs and they are in the import log then something is wrong. You can also try adding an additional filter to remove them based on an attribute they have in common.